# Can't access to json data with jquery mobile + phonegap + php

Tags: php, jquery, json, cordova

Hello I'm developping Android App with Jquery Mobile and PHP.
When I submit the login form my PHP script return a json data. But I cant access to these data in success function.

In the success function :

```
success: function (response,status) {
    console.log(response.etat);
    $.each(response, function(i, item){ 
        if ((item.etat == 'success') && (item.username == 'yes')) {
            $.mobile.changePage("#welcomepage");                        
        } else {
            console.log(item.etat);
        }
    });
},
```

the result of this script will be `Undefined`

but with this code :

```
success: function (response, status) {
    console.log(response);
} else {
    console.log("Error");
}
});
},
```

I have :

```
{     
    "username": "usertest",
    "password": "testpwd",
    "tag": "logintag",
    "etat":"success"
}
```

I dont undertand why when I do `response.username` I get nothing (`Undefined`)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
    my friend you will need to use json.parse onthe object which you get as response
    your code:- 
    success: function (response,status) {
        console.log(response.etat);
        $.each(response, function(i, item){ 
            if ((item.etat == 'success') && (item.username == 'yes')) {
                $.mobile.changePage("#welcomepage");                        
            } else {
                console.log(item.etat);
            }
        });
    }


    the code that will probablly work will be:-
    success: function (response,status) {
        console.log(response.etat);
var data=json.parse(response)        
$.each(data, function(i, item){ 
            if ((item.etat == 'success') && (item.username == 'yes')) {
                $.mobile.changePage("#welcomepage");                        
            } else {
                console.log(item.etat);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution but it's the same problem. Should I used any specific plugin? I used var = JSON.parse(response). thanks

Comment: There is more than 2 weeks that I'm trying to find solution but there still no solution.

Comment: It's okay now. I just did var = JSON.parse(response); if (data.status == 'success') { console.log('IT'S WORKS !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');}. Thank you